# How to make outline border to a range of dynamic cells / dynamic table in Openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

How to make Outline border using Openpyxl? Openpyxl doesn't have a feature to apply outline border to a range of dynamic cells or a dynamic table like in the image below:

[image: example]

The problem is that the table is dynamic, for a static table with defined number of rows/columns it is easy. But for variable number of rows/columns how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out using a link provided here: https://groups.google.com/g/openpyxl-users/c/R9QQ8yfowfc

Below code applies outline border to a dynamic range of cells in Openpyxl:

```
def add_outline_border(sheet, start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col):
    borderTop = Border(top = Side(style = 'thick'))
    borderBottom = Border(bottom = Side(style = 'thick'))
    borderLeft = Border(left = Side(style = 'thick'))                
    borderRight = Border(right = Side(style = 'thick')) 
    borderTopLeft = Border(left = Side(style = 'thick'), top=Side(style='thick'))
    borderTopRight = Border(right = Side(style = 'thick'), top=Side(style='thick'))
    borderBottomLeft = Border(left = Side(style = 'thick'), bottom = Side(style = 'thick'))
    borderBottomRight = Border(right = Side(style = 'thick'), bottom = Side(style = 'thick'))
    
    for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
        for col in range(start_col, end_col + 1):
            sheet.cell(start_row, col).border = borderTop
            sheet.cell(end_row, col).border = borderBottom
            sheet.cell(row, start_col).border = borderLeft
            sheet.cell(row, end_col).border = borderRight

    sheet.cell(start_row, start_col).border = borderTopLeft
    sheet.cell(start_row, end_col).border = borderTopRight
    sheet.cell(end_row, start_col).border = borderBottomLeft
    sheet.cell(end_row, end_col).border = borderBottomRight
    return sheet
```

Then call the function like:

```
sheet = add_outline_border(sheet, 2, 2, sheet.max_row, sheet.max_column)
```